# Разделение доступа RBAC на реакт

Tags: reactjs, redux

Бекенд моего приложения использует разделение доступа на основе rbac.
Есть базовые роли admin, user, guest ...
И есть роли кастомные, то есть права отдельному пользователю раздаются через админку, тем самым расширяя базовую роль.

Доступ к запрашиваемому методу проверяется путём наличия у пользователя определенного правила или роли.
На стороне бекенда всё выглядит неплохо.

Хотел бы узнать лучшие практики разруливания доступа RBAC в реакт приложении. Что для этого есть? Где можно подсмотреть.
Спасибо